# Whats a cleaner way to append something to a link URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-attributes

I've got this code so far, which isn't working:

```
$('.passName').click(function(){
    var schoolName = "18734";
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var newLink = link + schoolName;
    $(this).attr('href') = newLink;
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('href') = newLink;` gets an error

Comment: Some context into how this is being used and what isn't working would be helpful.

Comment: The problem with changing a link onclick is that your link will grow if you open targeting another tab...

Comment: Try this shorthand: `$(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '18734')`

Comment: @watson: That's not how you use [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do the following:

```
$(this).attr('href', newLink);
```

Comment: ... or just `this.href = newLink;`, in this case.

Answer (score 8):

There is a problem with your approach : you're appending the schoolName to the URL each time you click, even if the user targets another tab.

So I'd suggest to not mess with the `href` attribute but do the action on click :

```
   $('.passName').click(function(){
            location.href = this.href + "18734";
   });
```

or at least check you didn't add it before :

```
   $('.passName').click(function(){
       var schoolName = "18734";
       var link = this.href;
       if (link.indexOf(schoolName, link.length - schoolName.length)!==-1) {
           this.href = link+schoolName
       }
   });
```

or, as suggested by Felix Kling, simply ensure the function is called only once :

```
   $('.passName').one('click', function(){
       this.href += "18734"
   });
```

Comment: @VisioN I know, but this seems more reasonable anyway :)

Comment: awesome ...this is why I follow your answers..!!

Comment: Or use `.one` instead of `.click`, to execute the handler only once.

Comment: @FelixKling ... this looks like a good answer... Care to write it properly ?

Comment: Doesn't this break `Ctrl-click` to open the contents in a new tab?

Answer (score 1):

In Simple, do this way:-

```
$('.passName').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', this.href+'18734');
});
```

Comment: What's so right with using plain `this` in one place - but not in another, I wonder? It's quite ok to write just `this.href += '18734'`.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to create a new jQuery object, you can simply have:

```
$('.passName').click(function() {
   var schoolName = "18734";
   this.href += schoolName;
});
```

Library as jQuery as useful but we shouldn't forgot the plain JavaScript and DOM.

Plus, in JS you can't really "assign" something to a function call as you made; in jQuery the way to set an attribute's value is `$(this).attr('attr', newLink)`